# Codeigniter - How to set multiple template layout and assets (css,js and images)?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter php framework for my web project. My question is how to set multiple template layout and base path for assets such as css,js and images? I want to setup front end, login and back end layout. So there are 3 layouts I need to setup.

My project structure

[image]

These are samples code for my project.

MY_Controller.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class My_Controller extends CI_Controller {
  protected $layout = 'admin';

  protected $stylesheets = array(
    'app.css'
  );
  protected $javascripts = array(
  'app.js'
  );

  protected function render($content) {
    $view_data = array(
      'content' => $content,
      'stylesheets' => $this->get_stylesheets(),
      'javascripts' => $this->get_javascripts()
    );
    $this->load->view($this->layout,$view_data);
  }

  protected function get_stylesheets() {
    return $this->stylesheets;
  }

  protected function get_javascripts() {
    return $this->javascripts;
  }


}
```

Home.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends My_Controller {
  public function index() {
    $content = $this->load->view('home/index',null,true);
    $this->render($content);
  }
}

?>
```

I found this link on internet, but not suitable for my project. http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/reference.html

Comment: I use williamsconcepts template and it works very well for me. Why not suitable for you?? Just wondering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have used like this, may this sample will help you

**User Controller (controllers/user.php)**

```
<?php
    class User extends CI_Controller 
    {
        function displayuser()
        {
            $data['users'] = array(1,2,3);
            $data['inc_page'] = 'display'; // views/display.php page
            $this->load->view('user_layout', $data);
        }
    }
?>
```

**Display View (views/display.php)**

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
    <?php
        foreach($users as $userid)
        {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $userid;?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

**User Layout (views/user_layout.php)**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo $this->load->view($inc_page); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use site_url();
create a css folder in root.
let say the folder is named as "css".

Then let say we created file named style.css in that folder.
so we just need to call it in the site_url.

Comment: I believe you are thinking of `base_url()` which gives the document root (eg. http://domain/my/path), not `site_url()` which generates URLS for addressing controllers (ie http://domain/index.php/my/path).